# How to get the most recent row in group in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

In my mysql query, I try to get all threads with their most recent row.

```
    $query = "SELECT th.id, tm.message, tm.date_sent, tm.date_sent>tu.last_read_date AS new
              FROM thread th
              JOIN thread_user tu ON th.id=tu.thread_id AND tu.user_id={$user_id}
              JOIN thread_message tm ON th.id=tm.thread_id
              JOIN (
                   SELECT thread_id, MAX(date_sent) date_sent
                   FROM thread_message
                   GROUP BY thread_id
              ) q ON tm.thread_id = q.thread_id AND tm.date_sent = q.date_sent
              ORDER BY tm.date_sent DESC";
```

This works, but the problem is, if there is two or more rows who's date is the most recent and they are the same date, then it will join with both of them. I need that third join statement to join with at most 1 row.

I also don't want to assume that the biggest id implies its the most recent row, because I could always change the dates manually later.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What determines which message should be returned between the ties?  You can establish a row number per group and then return only the first in each set...

Comment: If there is more than 1 message with the same most recent date in a thread, then it should pick the one with the biggest id value. How do I do that row number establishing?

Comment: Actually, what if the maximum id, is not the row with the most recent date?

Comment: I just tried, and it then returned no records.

Comment: Good point... Perhaps you'll need that row number...

Comment: I tried a `GROUP BY th.id` before the `ORDER BY`, and that sorta fixes it. Now the problem is it doesn't pick the message with the biggest id.

Comment: That's actually just returning a random id (something that's not allowed in most other database systems, but mysql allows it unfortunately).  I posted a solution which creates a row number per group.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to establish a row number per group, in this case your group is `thread_id` and `date_sent`.  With `MySql`, you need to use `user-defined variables` to do this:

```
SELECT th.id, 
    tm.message, 
    tm.date_sent, 
    tm.date_sent>tu.last_read_date AS new
FROM thread th
    JOIN thread_user tu ON th.id=tu.thread_id AND tu.user_id={$user_id}
    JOIN (
        SELECT id,
               thread_id, 
               message, 
               date_sent, 
               @rn:=IF(@prevthread_id=thread_id, @rn+1, 1) rn,
               @prevthread_id:=thread_id
        FROM thread_message, (SELECT @rn:=1, @prevthread_id:=0) t
        ORDER BY thread_id, date_sent DESC, id
    ) tm ON th.id=tm.thread_id
           AND tm.rn = 1 
ORDER BY tm.date_sent DESC
```

---

Perhaps this is easier for you (but only because you're using `mysql`):

```
SELECT th.id, 
    tm.message, 
    tm.date_sent, 
    tm.date_sent>tu.last_read_date AS new
FROM thread th
    JOIN thread_user tu ON th.id=tu.thread_id AND tu.user_id={$user_id}
    JOIN thread_message tm ON th.id=tm.thread_id
    JOIN (
        SELECT thread_id, 
               id, 
               MAX(date_sent) date_sent
        FROM thread_message
        GROUP BY thread_id
    ) q ON tm.thread_id = q.thread_id 
           AND q.id = tm.id 
           AND tm.date_sent = q.date_sent
ORDER BY tm.date_sent DESC
```

This will return an arbitrary `id` to join on.

Comment: This still has the problem of joining with two rows with the same recent date.

Comment: @omega -- hmmm, perhaps I misunderstood something, sample data and desired results would make this easier.  However, given you're using `mysql`, review edits...

Comment: @omega -- also updated the row number routine as I now think I understand your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that if the query produces what you expect, with exception of the last `JOIN` you can just modify the `GROUP BY` which will only return one row.

```
JOIN (
      SELECT thread_id, MAX(date_sent) date_sent
      FROM thread_message
      GROUP BY thread_id
      ) q ON tm.thread_id = q.thread_id AND tm.date_sent = q.date_sent
      GROUP BY tm.date_sent
      ORDER BY tm.date_sent DESC";
```

Comment: If you do that, then you could return a max date associated with another thread id. Plus there is still the problem of not getting the max id with the recent date.

Comment: How bout the second one?